# How to solve a function explicitly using sympy

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I am trying to go above and beyond for a numerical analysis class by analytically solving this differential equation (don't worry about solving; I just want y'all to know where I am coming from):
[image]

Here, v is the dependent variable and t is our independent variable, so I would like to solve for v explicitly as a function of t. An initial condition is given: v(0) = 0.

Here is the solution that I got for the differential equation. I am certain it is correct, but if you'd like to try it for yourself, then be my guest.

[image]

And the plot for this series in desmos looks like this:

[image]

The only way to calculate this analytically is by the use of a power series expansion. So basically, the expression on the left is a large polynomial as a f(v), but this is not what I want.

I would like to be able to plot this function using matplotlib, and I would like to be able to get the velocity at any value of t.

I am very new to sympy so I am not familiar with everything yet, but here is a little bit of code to at least get the expression on the left side of the equation:

```
import sympy as sp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    drag_coefficient = 1.85
    g = 9.81
    m = 100
    rho = 1.2
    A = 30

    a = (drag_coefficient * rho * A)/(2*m)

    v = sp.Symbol('v')
    f_ana = (a**0 * v**(2*0 + 1))/(g**(0 + 1) * (2*0 + 1))
    for i in range(1, 101):
        f_ana = f_ana + (a**i * v**(2*i + 1))/(g**(i + 1) * (2*i + 1))

    print(f_ana)
```

And the output for f_ana is as expected:

```
6.0625809125107e-151*v**201 + 1.80395335070212e-149*v**199 + 5.36830184251333e-148*v**197 + 1.59769293782798e-146*v**195 + 4.75549130283346e-145*v**193 + 1.41561158253442e-143*v**191 .....
```

But then I try to calculate the velocity at a time (t) by doing something like this:

```
sp.solve(f_ana + 1, v) # calculating at t = 1s
```

And the program won't finish. I am assuming it's because this expression has virtually an infinite number of roots.

Are there any ideas for getting this equation as a function of t? I've thought about maybe finding the inverse of the function on the left side of the expression and then taking that inverse function of -t, but I don't know where to start with that. But if I can get the valid expression as a function of t then I should have no problem lambdifying the function and plotting it in matplotlib.

EDIT

I used the Runge-Kutta midpoint method for approximating v(t), and this is what the graph looks like:

[image]

This is the shape of the power series equation above, but I notice that if I expand the series more in desmos, the function gets sharper and closer to the shape of my approximated plot.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are trying to solve is a polynomial equation with floating point coefficients and is extremely ill conditioned with coefficients ranging over 150 orders of magnitude. With exact coefficients it would be possible for sympy to compute the roots using e.g. `Poly(f_ana).nroots()` although you would likely need to use a very high precision and the calculation would need to be slow due to the poor conditioning.

You say that this can only be solved by power-series methods but actually the substitution `x = v'` gives a separable ODE and SymPy can solve this:

```
In [1]: v = Function('v')

In [2]: m, c_d, rho, A, g, t = symbols('m, c_d, rho, A, g, t')

In [3]: eq = Eq(m*Derivative(v(t), t), c_d*rho*A*v(t)**2/2 - m*g)

In [4]: eq
Out[4]: 
                      2         
  d          A⋅c_d⋅ρ⋅v (t)      
m⋅──(v(t)) = ───────────── - g⋅m
  dt               2            

In [5]: dsolve(eq, v(t))
Out[5]: 
                   _____________
                  ╱      1      
        √2⋅g⋅m⋅  ╱  ─────────── 
               ╲╱   A⋅c_d⋅g⋅m⋅ρ 
v(t) = ─────────────────────────
           ⎛          √2⋅t     ⎞
           ⎜     C₁ - ────     ⎟
           ⎜           2       ⎟
       tanh⎜───────────────────⎟
           ⎜      _____________⎟
           ⎜     ╱      1      ⎟
           ⎜m⋅  ╱  ─────────── ⎟
           ⎝  ╲╱   A⋅c_d⋅g⋅m⋅ρ ⎠
```

EDIT: There are many different ways of writing the solution to this ODE. Since you have simplified the ODE itself now I'll show how to get a simpler answer from sympy:

```
In [86]: a, g = symbols('a, g', positive=True)

In [87]: v = Function('v')

In [88]: eq = Eq(v(t).diff(t), a*v(t)**2 - g)

In [89]: sol = dsolve(eq, v(t))

In [90]: sol
Out[90]: 
                  √g          
v(t) = ───────────────────────
       √a⋅tanh(√a⋅√g⋅(C₁ - t))
```

This is a solution of the ODE as you can easily verify by substituting it back into the ODE. The question is how this is in a different form to what you have come up with and the answer is that there are many ways to write the same function and also you need to bear in mind that the integration constant can be complex in general. If we take the initial condition `v(0) = 0` then we can solve for the integration constant:

```
In [91]: C1 = Symbol('C1')

In [92]: e1, e2 = solve(sol.rhs.subs(t, 0), C1)

In [93]: e1
Out[93]: 
 -ⅈ⋅π  
───────
2⋅√a⋅√g

In [94]: sol.subs(C1, e1)
Out[94]: 
                     √g             
v(t) = ─────────────────────────────
              ⎛      ⎛       ⅈ⋅π  ⎞⎞
       √a⋅tanh⎜√a⋅√g⋅⎜-t - ───────⎟⎟
              ⎝      ⎝     2⋅√a⋅√g⎠⎠

In [95]: sol.subs(C1, e1).simplify()
Out[95]: 
       -√g⋅tanh(√a⋅√g⋅t) 
v(t) = ──────────────────
               √a
```

The form that you found needs a different value for the integration constant but will also come out the same once you find the particular solution:

```
In [97]: sol = Eq(v(t), 2*sqrt(g/a) / (C1*exp(2*t*a*sqrt(g/a)) + 1) - sqrt(g/a))

In [98]: sol
Out[98]: 
         √g            2⋅√g         
v(t) = - ── + ──────────────────────
         √a      ⎛    2⋅√a⋅√g⋅t    ⎞
              √a⋅⎝C₁⋅ℯ          + 1⎠

In [99]: solve(sol.rhs.subs(t, 0), C1)
Out[99]: [1]

In [100]: e, = solve(sol.rhs.subs(t, 0), C1)

In [101]: sol.subs(C1, e)
Out[101]: 
         √g           2⋅√g       
v(t) = - ── + ───────────────────
         √a      ⎛ 2⋅√a⋅√g⋅t    ⎞
              √a⋅⎝ℯ          + 1⎠

In [102]: sol.subs(C1, e).rewrite(tanh)
Out[102]: 
         √g              2⋅√g           
v(t) = - ── + ──────────────────────────
         √a      ⎛    tanh(√a⋅√g⋅t) + 1⎞
              √a⋅⎜1 + ─────────────────⎟
                 ⎝    1 - tanh(√a⋅√g⋅t)⎠

In [103]: sol.subs(C1, e).rewrite(tanh).simplify()
Out[103]: 
       -√g⋅tanh(√a⋅√g⋅t) 
v(t) = ──────────────────
               √a
```

Comment: I tried plugging in the constants and plotting, but it doesn't look like the solution. See my edit above. I am certain that it should take the shape of my approximation. Also, I did use separation of variables to solve the ODE, and the power series is a result of the integral of 1/(a*v^2 - g)dv. It makes sense what you said about the floating point errors causing the problems.

Comment: You don't need a power series. Just look at the derivative of `arctanh`: `1/(1-x^2)`

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on here with sympy, but this is not the solution. I've detailed the solution to this problem in my report (the link in my answer). It is correct.

Comment: Have you checked that the solutions are not equivalent? There are many different ways to write exponentials, hyperbolics and logarithms in terms of each other. You should also bear in mind that the constant C can in general be complex.

Answer (score 0):

The method in my first answer is technically the correct solution as well, but there is another way to arrive at the solution to this differential equation. It is separable and can be solved by implementing integration by partial fractions. The final solution comes to this:
[image]

More details on how this solution came to be maybe found here:
https://github.com/gabemorris12/Miscellaneous/blob/main/Engineering%20Analysis/Parachute%20Project%20Merged.pdf